# Best practices for modularize aws lambda code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have been checking some resources on internet and all the examples of lambda in AWS are very basic but I am not sure how we will modularize an application with multiples dependencies, for example in java we usually have some structure like this

```
packages
  repository
  controllers
  ..
  ..
```

And we place the code related to each logic inside the package, but now in AWS seems that is more like scripting that will glue the pieces than OOP that I am used to, so my question is how we handle (if apply) this relationships, because I have seen code that all the logic is in one lambda and that not seems the best way to go, for example if we had some functionality that fist authenticate, authorize, transform, call an external api, get the response and then do a call to a final rest endpoint,  how we can split this, for example will be the same lambda with packages(directories) inside and we call to each other? or we have multiples lambdas each one with one purpose? and this will generate cold start for each lambda?

I was thinking in using layers, but seems very new and not sure if this is production ready feature and seems that is more related to reuse code that is common across all the environment that the way to modularize our code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally when you're developing Lambda functions, the function should have a single purpose (which will keep the function relatively small).

If you have multiple actions, by having each Lambda as its own function it will improve the development and deployment experience. Having a single developer working on the function reduces the risk of breaking unrelated functionality, whilst also allowing them to deploy only the function that they've worked on.

To orchestrate between Lambdas for APIs people tend to use [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) (be that for your clients communicating to the Lambdas, or between the Lambdas themselves).

Regarding any shared dependencies/libraries [Lambda Layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) as you mentioned is the correct way to go. It will allow you to centralise the dependencies that your applications share rather than the need to package the Lambda with a version of the dependencies each time.

There's an article on [Best Practices for Developing on AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/best-practices-for-developing-on-aws-lambda/) that should offer additional guidance.

Comment: Ok I understand, so that means that oop is no longer used in this context, so is more like functional programming?

Comment: Kind of, you can of course build shared libraries that would be included in your layers. But you generally wouldn't build classes in your Lambda function, you can of course if it helps :)